# Calculate min / max of two values in Less

Tags: less, max, min

How do i get the maximum or minimum of two values in Less. Just like Math.min() or Math.max() in javascript. I think this will be useful to use in your mixins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been implemented in the meantime. Have a look at the official Function Reference:

- [min()](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions-min)
- [max()](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions-max)

Answer (score 2):

Less min/max builtin functions are planned for future releases, see: https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1371. For now you could try, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982103/1596547:

```
.max(@a,@b)
{
   @max: ~"@{b}px";
}
.max(@a,@b) when (@a>@b)
{
   @max: ~"@{a}px";
}
.max(700,800);

.examplemax{width: @max;}
```

resulting in:

```
.examplemax {
  width: 800px;
}
```

or

```
.min(@a,@b)
{
   @min: ~"@{b}px";
}
.min(@a,@b) when (@a<@b)
{
   @min: ~"@{a}px";
}
.min(700,800);

.examplemin{width: @min;}
```

resulting in:

```
.examplemin {
  width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### More Compact

I would use the inline javascript capability of LESS to achieve this and add a flexibility to the units (which could be set to a default of `''` for just giving back the straight number if desired, but in my example default is `px`). Like so:

**LESS**

```
.minmax(@a,@b,@unit:'px') {
  @min: ~"`Math.min(@{a},@{b})`@{unit}";
  @max: ~"`Math.max(@{a},@{b})`@{unit}";
}
.test {
  .minmax(700,800);
  width: @max;
}
.test2 {
  .minmax(50,70,"%");
  width: @min;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  width: 800px;
}
.test2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Since you reference the javascript functions in your question, perhaps you were unaware of these inline capabilities that can interface with LESS.

Comment: very nice. you are right i didn't know about inline javascript capability. Thanks. I also do not find them here, so will there be any documentation for this? I will need a max here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10465. I'm not sure which solution i should prefer the more compact or the more pure Less.