# Use 2 Css LESS variables and subtract one from the other

Tags: css, math, less, stylesheet, calc

In less, I have the following:

```
@divwidth: 425px;
@docwidth: '$(window).width()';
```

I'd like to set the left style to the result of this:

```
left: ((@docwidth - @divwidth + 1)/2)!important;
```

I'm using the +1 in case I get a 0 and try to divide it by 2

I can't seem to get a proper value nor find out if I'm doing it right.
I've tried

```
left: ~'((docwidth - divwidth + 1) / 2)px' !important;
left: ~'calc((docwidth - divwidth + 1) / 2)px' !important;
```

Still no joy. I'd appreciate some help or a good resource to figure this out...

Comment: Never seen anyone using Javascript inside LESS... Are you sure it is supported? As far as I know, LESS is statically transformed into CSS, so I don't think that would work.

Comment: Looking at the docs, there's no mention of using Javascript expressions, apparently your idea is not possible with LESS alone. But since you can use Javascript, why not do it all from JS?

Comment: possible you you should explain what you want to achieve, to find a better solution for your problem

Comment: Probably what you need instead is something like ["viewport units"](http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/). By using `$(window).width()` in your Less code you're really asking for trouble (+100 to **Bass Jobsen** answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use JavaScript evaluating in your Less code. JavaScript code should be placed between backticks `` @docwidth: "`$(window).width()`"; `` , see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386571/1596547 for an example.

The usage of JavaScript in Less has been deprecated, because alternative compilers (not written in JavaScript) can not compile your code.

Also notice that `$(window).width()` only makes sense when using [the client side compiler](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) and even then you should recompile your code after resizing your window (calling less.refreshStyles()).

In most situations you use less to compile static CSS code. Static CSS code does not change / respond on environment properties such as  `$(window).width()`.

Comment: I will give it a try... I'll check in with my results, thanks.