# Generating the value of CSS content in LESS loop

Tags: css, less

We have a CSS style that adds dots before and after a heading indicating the nesting level of the heading:

```
.heading.nesting-1:before,.heading.nesting-1:after{content:"\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-2:before,.heading.nesting-2:after{content:"\00B7\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-3:before,.heading.nesting-3:after{content:"\00B7\00B7\00B7"}
...
```

I have tried the following LESS but it doesn't concatenate the strings correctly

```
@entity-dot: '\00B7';
@nesting-levels: 9;

.heading {
   .nesting-loop (@i) when (@i <= @nesting-levels) {
      &.nesting-@{i} {
         &:before, &:after  {
            .nested-dots(@j, @current: "") when (@j > 0) {
               @nested-dots: "@{current}@{entity-dot}";
               .nested-dots((@j - 1), @nested-dots);
            }
            .nested-dots(@j: @i, "");
            content: "@{nested-dots}";
         }
      }
      .nesting-loop(@i + 1);
   }
   .nesting-loop (1);
}
```

The result is:

```
.heading.nesting-1:before,.heading.nesting-1:after{content:"\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-2:before,.heading.nesting-2:after{content:"\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-3:before,.heading.nesting-3:after{content:"\00B7"}
...
```

I think I understand that the problem is that the property `@nested-dots` cannot be iteratively updated in this way but I was wondering if anybody had a solution?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it with the help of this post
[(thank you Martin Turjak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975459/concatenate-string-in-less-in-loop)

```
@nesting-levels: 5;
@entity-space: '\00A0';
@entity-dot: '\00B7';

.content-dots (@numdots) {

    //Mixin output
    .nested-dots(1, @dots1) {
        @dots: "@{dots1}@{entity-dot}";
    }

    //Mixin iterator
    .nested-dots(@index, @dots1) when (@index > 1) {
        @dots2: "@{dots1}@{entity-dot}@{entity-space}";
        .nested-dots((@index - 1), @dots2);
    }

    //Call mixin
    .nested-dots(@numdots, "");

    //Output dots
    content: "@{dots}";
}

.heading {
    .nesting-loop (@i) when (@i >= 1) {
        &.nesting-@{i} {
            &:before, &:after  {
                .content-dots(@i);
            }
        }
        .nesting-loop (@i - 1);
    }
    .nesting-loop (@nesting-levels);
}
```

The result is

```
.heading.nesting-5:before,.heading.nesting-5:after{content:"\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-4:before,.heading.nesting-4:after{content:"\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-3:before,.heading.nesting-3:after{content:"\00B7\00A0\00B7\00A0\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-2:before,.heading.nesting-2:after{content:"\00B7\00A0\00B7"}
.heading.nesting-1:before,.heading.nesting-1:after{content:"\00B7"}
```